# reflect property file changes in osgi bundle without restarting Karaf Server

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, jbossfuse

How can i configure my Karaf Server in such a way that whenever there is a property file change, i should not restart my server for getting those changes in staead it should atomatically detect thos changes. I deploying my bundle in osgi Karaf Server. For loading property file i am using below configuration in my camel context.

```
<bean 
class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" 
id="properties">
<property name="locations">
<list><value>file:etc/app/properties/env/env.properties</value>
<value>file:etc/vrol/security/ssl.properties
</value></list></property></bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are currently not using an OSGi mechanism to load the property file. As far as I know you can only achieve this by switching from spring to blueprint.

In blueprint you can define a config like this:

```
<cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="myconfig" update-strategy="reload" >
</cm:property-placeholder>
```

This will load the config from etc/myconfig.cfg and will reload the blueprint context when the config changes.

Comment: thanks @christian schneider, but i am using Spring DSL. Do u mean that it impossible to have the same thing working with spring DSL?

Comment: There is also a blueprint dsl that is almost identical to the spring dsl.

Comment: yes, so how can i acheive this in Spring DSl? Do i have to change the way i am loading my property i.e currently i am using BridgePropertyPlaceholder . If then can you please tell how can we acheie this

Comment: See http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html . Using Blueprint Property Placeholder with Camel Routes